# How to impute an ordinal variable with MICE but prevent it from taking one value?

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

I have an ordinal variable, `overall_tumor_grade`, that can take on values of `1`, `2`, `3`, or `X` if the measurement is indeterminable. There are some `NA`s that I want to impute using the `mice` package in R, but I know that the missing values cannot be `X` because their tumor sizes are greater than `0`. I want to impute `overall_tumor_grade` but force `mice` to only choose from `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Here is sample code for you to use:

```
df=data.frame(age=c(24,37,58,65,70,84),
    overall_tumor_grade=c(1,1,2,3,'X',NA),
    tumor_size=c(1.5,2.0,4.2,5.6,0,0.1))
imp=mice(df)
na_index=which(is.na(df$overall_tumor_grade))
complete(imp)$overall_tumor_grade[na_index]  #This can never be 'X'
```

Thank you for your help and please let me know if you need more information.

---

### New addition

@longrob suggested I temporarily remove the patients with `X` observations, impute, then add them back in to the full dataset.  Would the imputation lose power by removing all of those observations?  Along @longrob's suggestion, here is the work-around I have right now using a sample dataframe that is closer to what I'm really working with (several columns with missing values):

```
df=data.frame(age=rnorm(mean=45,sd=10,25),
overall_tumor_grade=factor(sample(c(1,2,3,'X'),25,replace=TRUE)),
tumor_size=runif(25)*10)
df[df$overall_tumor_grade=='X','tumor_size']=0 #Patients with Grade 'X' have tumorsz=0
df[sample(1:25,3),'age']=NA   ##Setting some observations to NA
df[sample(1:25,5),'overall_tumor_grade']=NA
df[sample(1:25,1),'tumor_size']=NA
################ Imputation
imp=mice(df,meth=c('pmm',"",'pmm'))  #Suppress imputation of overall_tumor_grade
dfimp=complete(imp)
dfimp2=dfimp[dfimp$overall_tumor_grade!='X',]  #I don't want to impute grade 'X' tumors
#so I am trying to remove those observations here and then use droplevels(), but for 
#a reason I can't figure out, that statement is setting all rows to NA where grade='X'
```

Any suggestions on how I accomplish what @longrob suggested?

Comment: Can we assume that all instances of overall_tumor_grade == 'X' also have tumor_size == 1? I think the answer might be to construct a data.frame without any rows with 'X', and then do the imputation on that, but that only works if the above assumption is true.

Comment: We cannot assume that because by definition grade 'X' means that the tumor size=0

Comment: @atiretoo I don't see why that assumption is needed ? If there are any observations with tumor_size==0 and overall_tumor_grade==NA just recode those NAs as X. Then delete observations with overall_tumor_grade==NA and run the imputations..... ?

Comment: @longrob all of the patients that have tumor sizes of 0 are already coded as grade 'X'.  All of the missing overall_tumor_grade observations have tumor sizes >0, and the problem I'm having is that MICE is imputing some of those NAs as grade 'X'.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized there's a typo in my comment, should be tumor size == 0, so your response answers the question, thanks. In your additional code the reason why rows with overall_tumor_grade == NA are set to NA, is that any comparison with NA results in NA, not TRUE or FALSE. You can get around that by picking out the rows with tumor_size == 0, hence my botched question about the data above.

Answer (score 12):

The following code defines and calls a dedicated imputation function that separates imputation of cases with tumor_size == 0 from tumor_size > 0.

```
## How to impute an ordinal variable with MICE but prevent it from taking one value?

df <- data.frame(age = c(24,37,58,65,70,84),
                 overall_tumor_grade = c(1,1,2,3,'X',NA),
                 tumor_size = c(1.5,2.0,4.2,5.6,0,0.1))

mice.impute.tumor <- function(y, ry, x, ...){
    ymis <- y[!ry]
    tmis <- x$tumor_size[!ry] > 0
        t  <- x$tumor_size > 0
    y[!ry] <- NA
    ymis[!tmis] <- "X"
    ymis[tmis] <- mice.impute.polyreg(y[t, drop = TRUE], ry[t], x[t,], ...)
    ymis
}

ini <- mice(df, maxit = 0)
meth <- ini$meth
meth["overall_tumor_grade"] <- "tumor"
imp <- mice(df, meth = meth, maxit = 1, m = 2)
```

Comment: Versions prior to `mice 3.0.0` used the now retired `padModel()` function to create the design matrix. That function returned a data frame. Since `mice 3.0.0` we use `base::model.matrix()`, which returns a matrix, so the `$` operator on `x` does not work anymore. Patrick Rockenschaub provided an update https://github.com/amices/mice/issues/224#issuecomment-693935305

Answer (score 8):

Maybe there is a better way, but the only way I know is to remove the observations with tumor size X from the dataset, then remove the unused level X from the variable definitions (with `droplevels()` for example) and then run `mice()`

**Update1:**
OK, there was a typo in my comment last night - I meant to change that line to `dfimp2=dfimp[dfimp$overall_tumor_grade!='X' | is.na(dfimp$overall_tumor_grade),]`  Sorry about that. Anyway, here's my approach to this problem, based on your simulated dataset:

```
set.seed(100)
df=data.frame(age=rnorm(mean=45,sd=10,25), 
overall_tumor_grade=factor(sample(c(1,2,3,'X'),25,replace=TRUE)), 
tumor_size=runif(25)*10) 
df[df$overall_tumor_grade=='X','tumor_size']=0 #Patients with Grade 'X' have tumorsz=0 
df[sample(1:25,3),'age']=NA   ##Setting some observations to NA 
df[sample(1:25,5),'overall_tumor_grade']=NA 
df[sample(1:25,1),'tumor_size']=NA 

# output the data
df

        age overall_tumor_grade tumor_size
1        NA                   2         NA
2  46.31531                   1  8.5665304
3  44.21083                   1  7.7477889
4  53.86785                   2  8.3402710
5  46.16971                   3  0.9151028
6  48.18630                   2  4.5952549
7  39.18209                   1  5.9939816
8  52.14533                   1  9.1972191
9        NA                   3  9.8282408
10       NA                <NA>  0.3780258
11 45.89886                   2  5.7793740
12 45.96274                   3  7.3331417
13 42.98366                   X  0.0000000
14 52.39840                <NA>  3.0073652
15 46.23380                <NA>  7.3346670
16 44.70683                <NA>  9.0695438
17 41.11146                   2  2.0981677
18 50.10856                   2  3.5813799
19 35.86186                   1  4.4829914
20 68.10297                   3  9.0642643
21 40.61910                   2  3.8943930
22 52.64061                <NA>  5.1745975
23 47.61961                   3  1.2523909
24 52.73405                   X  0.0000000
25 36.85621                   3  7.7180549

# rows 13 and 24 have tumor grade X

# vector for which rows do not have tumor grade X
vx <- df$overall_tumor_grade!='X' | is.na(df$overall_tumor_grade) 
# remove those with tumor grade X
dfimp <- df[vx,]

# do the imputations
dfimp$overall_tumor_grade <- droplevels(dfimp$overall_tumor_grade)
imp=mice(dfimp, printFlag=F) 

# add back the rows we removed
(new_df1 <- rbind(complete(imp,1),df[!vx,]))

1  40.61910                   2  3.8943930
2  46.31531                   1  8.5665304
3  44.21083                   1  7.7477889
4  53.86785                   2  8.3402710
5  46.16971                   3  0.9151028
6  48.18630                   2  4.5952549
7  39.18209                   1  5.9939816
8  52.14533                   1  9.1972191
9  45.89886                   3  9.8282408
10 52.14533                   3  0.3780258
11 45.89886                   2  5.7793740
12 45.96274                   3  7.3331417
14 52.39840                   2  3.0073652
15 46.23380                   3  7.3346670
16 44.70683                   2  9.0695438
17 41.11146                   2  2.0981677
18 50.10856                   2  3.5813799
19 35.86186                   1  4.4829914
20 68.10297                   3  9.0642643
21 40.61910                   2  3.8943930
22 52.64061                   3  5.1745975
23 47.61961                   3  1.2523909
25 36.85621                   3  7.7180549
13 42.98366                   X  0.0000000
24 52.73405                   X  0.0000000
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a simple way to do this but I'm hitting a road block because in my data set (i.e. not the sample I posted) there are multiple columns that I am imputing at once.  I can suppress imputation of the overall_tumor_grade column while letting the others proceed, but I'm running into trouble trying to then impute overall_tumor_grade while removing the 'X' observations.  I'll post some more code in my question to illustrate.

Comment: @JJM, looking at your additional code, try changing the last line to `dfimp2=dfimp[dfimp$overall_tumor_grade!='X' | is.na(df$overall_tumor_grade),]` - sorry I don't have time to test this or look in detail, as I have to go to bed now for an early rise (here in UK) but I'll check back on this question tomorrow.

Comment: @JJM see my updated answer. Hope it helps !

Comment: Yeah, so that works as long as there are no missing values in other variables in rows with overall_tumor_grade == 'X'. I suppose you could run the imputation a second time after adding the rows back?

Comment: @atiretoo , yes, or the other way around (which is what the OP was going to do in the **"New addition"** section of the question, I think, before running into the problem of selecting on NAs)