# How to impute a categorical variable with MICE but prevent it from taking some values?

Tags: categorical-data, data-imputation, mice

I have a categorical variable, var1 , that can take on values of W, B, A, M, N or P. There are some NAs that I want to impute using the mice package in R, but I know that the missing values cannot be "W" or "B" because those people said that they do not belong in that category. I want to impute var1 but force mice to only choose from everything except B or W .

Here is sample code for you to use:

```
df=data.frame(age=c(24,37,58,65,70,84, 56, 36, 48,23,15),
    var1 =c("B","W", NA, "A",NA, "P","N", NA, "M",NA, "B"),
    var1categ=c(0,0, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 0),
    ht = c(156, 169, 180, 175, 168, 165, 171, 158, 160, 175, 160))


imp=mice(df, remove_collinear = FALSE)
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: A good question for a programming-related site; not so much for this one, though, because the question is about the mechanics of assigning values to data using code.

Comment: @rolando2 I found here a similar question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32179/how-to-impute-an-ordinal-variable-with-mice-but-prevent-it-from-taking-one-value and I thought that people in this site focus on issues like these :)

Comment: You're right that some programming questions without much statistical content per se slip through the cracks.  But many such questions do get voted to be closed here.  I'd try https://stackoverflow.com/ or another R-focused site.  Cheers ~

Comment: @rolando2 I uploaded it also there. Thanks :) :)